# How can I loop over S3 objects that contain images using Python and Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-s3, django-views, jinja2

For context, my AWS S3 media folder consists of objects that are folders containing the images for advertisements. Each object in the bucket is one advertisement

In local, I can loop over each image within a folder and render it to the advertisement page however I can't get it to work in production.

The relevant view rendering the location looks like below:

```
def carmodel(request, carmodel_id):
carmodel = get_object_or_404(CarModel, id=carmodel_id)
folder_name = carmodel.title.replace(" ", '%20')
image_folder = os.listdir('media/'+carmodel.title)

return render(request, 'vehicles/vehicle.html', 
              {"carmodel": carmodel, "image_folder":image_folder, 
              "folder_name":folder_name})
```

Each folder is named using the carmodels title. And in the vehicles.html file, I'm looping over it like so.

```
        {% for image in image_folder %}
          <img src="/media/{{ folder_name }}/{{ image }}" class="slider-thumbnail">
        {% endfor %}
```

I know that the os.listdir from the image_folder variable within carmodel view doesn't work in production. But I'm stuck trying to figure out how to fix it.

I'm ultimately trying to construct the media url by using MEDIA_URL, then folder name then at the end, at the iteration for each image . Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

def get_image_names_from_s3(bucket_name, folder_name):
    # Initialize the S3 client
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    # Fetch the objects (files) in the given folder
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=folder_name)
    
    # Extract the image file names from the response
    image_files = [content['Key'].split('/')[-1] for content in response.get('Contents', []) if content['Key'].lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'))]
    
    return image_files

def yourview(request):
    bucket_name = 'your_bucket_name'
    folder_name = 'folder/sub_folder/'  # Ensure it ends with '/'
    image_names = get_image_names_from_s3(bucket_name, folder_name)
    context = {'names': image_names}
    return render(request, 'yourpage.html', context)

{% for i in names %}
<div class="col-12 col-md-8 my-3">
    <div class="yourclass" data-setbg="{% static 'path_to_link'|add:i %}" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Explanation:

This is a Python function intended to interact with Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service) and a Django view function that uses the former.
The Django HTML template code at the bottom aims to display the image names retrieved from S3.

Here's a breakdown of each part:

1. Importing boto3: The boto3 library is used to interact with AWS services, including S3.

2 get_image_names_from_s3 Function:

- It takes bucket_name and folder_name as parameters.
- Initializes an S3 client.
- Lists objects in the given folder using list_objects_v2.
- Filters out image files and returns their names.

3. yourview Function:

- It's a Django view function.
- It calls get_image_names_from_s3 to get the image names.
- It passes the names to the template through the context dictionary.

Django Template Code

- Uses the Django templating engine to iterate over names (the image filenames).
- For each name, a div element is created.
- The data-setbg attribute is set using the name of the image file, which is appended to 'path_to_link'.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.